# Non-Root (VPN) firewall that filters based on SSID/Networkname for Android

Tags: android, vpn

I am looking for a firewall app based on VPN's (So I don't need to ROOT my device), with a specific twist: I want to block all applications except 1 (one) on a specific SSID-name. The reason is that I have a network on my office that is local only. And I have an app that needs that network, however I want to be able to access the internet through my 3G connection for other applications.
But when I come home (or on a public WIFI) I would like to use that connection of course.
So I am looking for an app that allows/redirects connections based on the SSID.

Comment: You might want to look into no-root firewalls with profiles.